# Read a text file using XMLHttpRequest?

Tags: html, xml, xmlhttprequest

I have been trying to use the XMLHttpRequest to read a text file and display the text. The text file I is going to be linked externally. So far I have the following code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>Using the XMLHttpRequest object</h2>

<script>
<script>
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("GET", XMLHttpRequest.txt, true);
</script>
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I do not see my text file showing up and I am completely lost. I looked around on stack overflow already for answers and I did not find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't specified where your text file is located.

Here's an example of a working XMLHttpRequest with a remote api (not a real api endpoint, just an example url). You could adapt this to use a text file instead of json. Remember to call your function in the end! `findCity( city )` for instance.

```js
function findCity(elem) {

        let xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
          if (xmlhttp.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
             if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                 document.getElementById("city").value = xmlhttp.responseText;
             }
             else if (xmlhttp.status == 400) {
                alert('There was an error 400');
             }
             else {
                 alert('something else other than 200 was returned');
             }
          }
      };

    xmlhttp.open("GET", "https://api.example.com/api/postcodes.json?pnr=" + elem.value + '&clientUrl=http://localhost', true);
      xmlhttp.send();
  }
```

Comment: My text file is locally on the computer under an assets folder. Would I do something like "assets/XMLHttpRequest.txt" ?

Comment: No, I don't think that will work. Use xmlhttp.open() instead, as in my example and use your local file instead of the https://api.example url. Not sure if you should use a slash before your file or not, try both (/file.txt or just file.txt). The syntax is like this: `XMLHttpRequest.open(method, url[, async[, user[, password]]])` so you remove everything from after `GET,` and before `, true`. True means it's asynchronously loaded.